# Swift 3 and code converter for looping arrays reversely

Tags: swift3

I have this code which is not compatible with swift3

```
for var i = FCatalogIdx-1; i > -1; i -=1 {
  // access items in array FCaalogArr 
}
```

Code converter suggest converting to

```
for i in ((-1 + 1)...FCatalogIdx-1).reversed() {
```

which seems to be the the same as:

```
for i in (0...FCatalogIdx-1).reversed() {
```

Is this the closest I can get to my old code? And if so, is it recommended to use the code converter suggestion - the *(-1 + 1)* looks ugly, but I suspect it is to give a hint of the original c-style loop logic?

Comment: If your goal is just to iterate FCatalogArr, just use `for element in FCatalogArr.reversed() {...`

Comment: I need to iterate starting from FCatalogIdx towards the beginning

Comment: do you actually need the to use the indices, or do you only care about the arrray's elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `(-1+1)` because that is just needlessly confusing. Also, use the *half-open range operator* `..<` to create a range that doesn't include the final index:

```
for i in (0 ..< FCatalogIdx).reversed() {
}
```

---

The advantage of the *half-open range operator* `..<` over the *closed range operator* `...` is that it is possible to create an empty range.

Consider this example:

```
let n = 0

for i in 0 ..< n {
    print("hello")    // range is empty, so this is never printed
}

for i in 0 ... n-1 {  // fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound
    print("hello")
}
```

Comment: I believe this looks to be the most clean solution - thanks!

Comment: @Tom, I added more info about the *half-open range operator* `..<`.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in FCaalogArr.indicies.reversed()` would be better assuming FCaalogIdx is the last index of the array